# Return application/octet-stream on endpoint from byte array

Tags: java, spring-boot, octet-stream

How can I return a byteArray on a Spring Boot Controller endpoint using MediaType of application/octet-stream ?
I know how to do it in case I want to return `application/json` :

```
@GetMapping(value = "/v1/example/json", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<List<ExampleObject>> getObjectsAsJson()
{
        List<ExampleObject> objectsList= objectsService.getObjects();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(objectsList, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

But how can I do it if I need to return `application/octet-stream` ?
This is what I have until now :

```
@GetMapping(value = "/v1/example/byte-array", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getOctetStreamBody()
{
        byte[] byteArray= fileService.getByteArray();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(byteArray, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Is it any good ?
Thanks!